# One big database versus many small databases

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, database-performance

My App deals with several similar datasets. That is, they are stored in the same tables, but different data. The user may create more datasets. In any case, these datasets are guaranteed to be disjunct. There will never be any data in one dataset linked somehow to data in another dataset.

I was wondering, would it be better to have a dedicated database for each dataset instead of having all the data in one big database?

I would expect lookup times to improve, if the user works on a smaller database. Is there a rule of thumb, how many entries a database (or table) can hold before I should worry about lookup times?

One drawback I can think of is that opening a database creates some overhead. However, I don't expect the user to switch datasets frequently.

**Consider this example:**

The database contains tables for companies, clients, products and orders. Companies never share clients or products, thus companies are the disjunct datasets. However, all products, clients and orders are in just one big table (for each, respectively).

Queries to the database might include:

- All orders for a particular client.
- All products a particular client has ordered.
- All clients who have ordered a particular product.
- etc.

These queries have in common, that they will always be issued in the context of one single company. Yet since the database doesn't know about this logical partition, *all* clients, products and orders will be searched.

If I were to have several databases, for each company one, my logical partition would be reflected and only the relevant data would be searched. I'm not sure of the overhead of having that many databases though.

Since I'm new to database schema design, I want to throw this idea out there to see, if several databases really are a good idea or not.

**Update:**

In case this wasn't clear: the database will be on the Android Phone, not in the Cloud or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rule of thumb. AFAIK the look-up time doesn't purely depend on number of entries. It depends on several factors such as but not limited to -

1. how fat the table is
2. table indexes
3. how the data is stored e.g. boolean true/false or string YES/NO in the table having 3 million records
4. hardware size
5. primary key/foreign key relationship (sort of connected to point 1 above)

As a general approach, one database theory is advisable. The servers nowadays are quite powerful and there are multiple options when it comes to handling the performance optimisation such as -

1. cloud databases which give the flexibility to choose the size
2. BigData
3. In-memory databases
4. Analysis services such as SSAS
5. NoSQL databases which are horizontally scalable e.g. FireStore

Now, the biggest benefit of using one database is - your development and testing will be quick. What does that mean ? Let's say you need to add/delete/modify one field in one table. Now, if you have 10 different databases then you will need to do the exact same change at 10 different places and then test it as well. If the changes are frequent then you might end-up in writing a generic script. And there is always a chance that this script might break e.g. database change, patch update blah blah. However, in the case of one database, the efforts are straight away 1/10th. Another benefit is database administration/monitoring will be easy e.g. adding indexes.

I had a similar requirement few months back wherein I've a similar application (mobile+web). The set-up is similar. Different companies access the data. And the user from a particular company is allowed to view data pertaining to his/her company. All I've done is to add one more column assigned as ORGCODE in almost every table. More than 12 clients are happily sharing the tables without any issues.

Disclaimer: All of the above is quite generic without knowing your use-case and performance requirement.

Comment: The database will be on the phone. I don't think changing the database schema would be such a big deal because since they're identical, they share the same Room Entities. I'd just open them under different names.

Comment: Got it. Checkout FireStore (which is a NoSQL db from Firebase). You can use different Collections in the same database to separate out the data. The following link might help - https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI Plus it has offline support.

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds me of some articles out there discussing the difference between relational databases and storing data as json or other noSQL options. Without doing some studies on what you are trying to accomplish and the scale that you might get to it is hard to judge. However, from a maintenance perspective, your database schema and its flexibility to change would favor the single db instance. You might go with multiple tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is question of pure performance. You should know how big should be your database and how much bigger will it be with all the data you ought to store in separate database - if this amount is around 20% of the general database and it will be only decreasing - use one database, if it may increase to allocate 50% or more of the general database - you may consider separate ones.

General size of database also matters. Modern devices may relatively comfortably work with databases up to 500mb(~500 000 heavy lines). It will handle more but it will require some modifications of UX and UI and scheme in order to minimize calls(pagination, indexes etc.). Although if you will run such an application of some weak device it will crush.

Also knowing how SQLite works(virtual tables in RAM) it is highly dependent on RAM amount accessible by an app. It is best to use db sized up to 100mb.

As you can see there is no single approach - you have to choose based on your app usecases and predicted size of database.

Hope this answer helps you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for one database - Less maintenance and stuff that can go wrong.
Make sure its optimized and indexed